# Cannot find updated row SQLite IOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, sqlite, insert-update

I have an app where I take details of the user and save it to SQLite db. Also I am able to find the details and display the result.

```
-(void) createDB{
NSString *docsDir;
NSArray *dirPaths;

// Get the documents directory
dirPaths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(
                                               NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);

docsDir = dirPaths[0];

// Build the path to the database file
_databasePath = [[NSString alloc]
                 initWithString: [docsDir stringByAppendingPathComponent:
                                  @"contactUnique6.db"]];

NSFileManager *filemgr = [NSFileManager defaultManager];

if ([filemgr fileExistsAtPath: _databasePath ] == NO)
{
    const char *dbpath = [_databasePath UTF8String];

    if (sqlite3_open(dbpath, &_contactDB) == SQLITE_OK)
    {
        char *errMsg;
        const char *sql_stmt =
        "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS CONTACTS (ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT , NAME TEXT , ADDRESS TEXT, PHONE TEXT )";

        if (sqlite3_exec(_contactDB, sql_stmt, NULL, NULL, &errMsg) != SQLITE_OK)
        {
            _status.text = @"Failed to create table";
        }
        sqlite3_close(_contactDB);
    } else {
        _status.text = @"Failed to open/create database";
    }
}



- (IBAction)saveData:(id)sender {
sqlite3_stmt    *statement;
const char *dbpath = [_databasePath UTF8String];

if (sqlite3_open(dbpath, &_contactDB) == SQLITE_OK)
{

    NSString *insertSQL = [NSString stringWithFormat:
                           @"INSERT OR IGNORE INTO CONTACTS (name, address, phone) VALUES (\"%@\", \"%@\", \"%@\")",
                           _name.text, _address.text, _phone.text];
      const char *insert_stmt = [insertSQL UTF8String];

    sqlite3_prepare_v2(_contactDB, insert_stmt,
                       -1, &statement, NULL);
    if (sqlite3_step(statement) == SQLITE_DONE)
    {
        _status.text = @"Contact added";
        _name.text = @"";
        _address.text = @"";
        _phone.text = @"";
    } else {
        _status.text = @"Failed to add contact";
    }
    sqlite3_finalize(statement);
    sqlite3_close(_contactDB);
}
```

}

```
- (IBAction)findContact:(id)sender {
const char *dbpath = [_databasePath UTF8String];

sqlite3_stmt    *statement;

if (sqlite3_open(dbpath, &_contactDB) == SQLITE_OK)
{
    NSString *querySQL = [NSString stringWithFormat:
                          @"SELECT address, phone FROM contacts WHERE name=\"%@\"",
                          _name.text];

    const char *query_stmt = [querySQL UTF8String];

    if (sqlite3_prepare_v2(_contactDB,
                           query_stmt, -1, &statement, NULL) == SQLITE_OK)
    {
        if (sqlite3_step(statement) == SQLITE_ROW)
        {
            NSString *addressField = [[NSString alloc]
                                      initWithUTF8String:
                                      (const char *) sqlite3_column_text(
                                                                         statement, 0)];
            _address.text = addressField;
            NSString *phoneField = [[NSString alloc]
                                    initWithUTF8String:(const char *)
                                    sqlite3_column_text(statement, 1)];
            _phone.text = phoneField;
            _status.text = @"Match found";
        } else {
            _status.text = @"Match not found";
            _address.text = @"";
            _phone.text = @"";
        }
        sqlite3_finalize(statement);
    }
    sqlite3_close(_contactDB);
}
```

}

The above code is working good. However when I am trying to use an update, it is not displaying when I try to find it. It gives me a match not found even though the contact was saved.

This is the code by which I am trying to update:

```
- (IBAction)saveData:(id)sender {
sqlite3_stmt    *statement;
const char *dbpath = [_databasePath UTF8String];

if (sqlite3_open(dbpath, &_contactDB) == SQLITE_OK)
{

    NSString *insertSQL = [NSString stringWithFormat:
                           @"INSERT OR IGNORE INTO CONTACTS (name, address, phone) VALUES (\"%@\", \"%@\", \"%@\")",
                           _name.text, _address.text, _phone.text];

    insertSQL = [NSString stringWithFormat:
                 @"UPDATE CONTACTS SET name=\"%@\", address=\"%@\", phone=\"%@\"",
                 _name.text, _address.text, _phone.text];

     const char *insert_stmt = [insertSQL UTF8String];
    sqlite3_prepare_v2(_contactDB, insert_stmt,
                       -1, &statement, NULL);
    if (sqlite3_step(statement) == SQLITE_DONE)
    {
        _status.text = @"Contact added";
        _name.text = @"";
        _address.text = @"";
        _phone.text = @"";
    } else {
        _status.text = @"Failed to add contact";
    }
    sqlite3_finalize(statement);
    sqlite3_close(_contactDB);
}
```

}

Basically my aim is to be able to save-update-find. (without losing the primary key on update, as I have FK relations)

**EDIT**
This is my create db method
    -(void) createDB{
    NSString *docsDir;
    NSArray *dirPaths;

```
// Get the documents directory
dirPaths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(
                                               NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);

docsDir = dirPaths[0];

// Build the path to the database file
_databasePath = [[NSString alloc]
                 initWithString: [docsDir stringByAppendingPathComponent:
                                  @"contactUnique6.db"]];

NSFileManager *filemgr = [NSFileManager defaultManager];

if ([filemgr fileExistsAtPath: _databasePath ] == NO)
{
    const char *dbpath = [_databasePath UTF8String];

    if (sqlite3_open(dbpath, &_contactDB) == SQLITE_OK)
    {
        char *errMsg;
        const char *sql_stmt =
        "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS CONTACTS (ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT , NAME TEXT , ADDRESS TEXT, PHONE TEXT )";

        if (sqlite3_exec(_contactDB, sql_stmt, NULL, NULL, &errMsg) != SQLITE_OK)
        {
            _status.text = @"Failed to create table";
        }
        sqlite3_close(_contactDB);
    } else {
        _status.text = @"Failed to open/create database";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

i cant get your second -(IBAction)saveData:(id)sender {} method [ Third code block ]..

You said above 2 blocks are working properly so its ok.

i think you embedded the update's logic in insert's logic i.e. you embedded the update method in your saveData method..

Here i cant get what u have done, so instead of code here i m providing the template for update query, just put your code in it...

```
sqlite3_stmt *statement;
if(sqlite3_open(dbpath, &database_object) == SQLITE_OK)
{
    NSString *sql = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"update table_name set column_name = \"%@\"", Your_value];
    const char *sql_stmt = [sql UTF8String];
    if(sqlite3_prepare_v2(database_object , sql_stmt, -1, &statement, NULL) != SQLITE_OK)
         NSLog(@"Error while creating update statement. '%s'", sqlite3_errmsg(database_object));
    if(SQLITE_DONE != sqlite3_step(statement))
         NSLog(@"Error while updating. '%s'", sqlite3_errmsg(database_object));
    sqlite3_finalize(statement);
}
```

Go with this template, i think it will work for you...